# How do I remove Yahoo as my default search engine in Safari?

Tags: google-workspace, browser, safari

I am a user of the latest Mac system. My Default browser is Safari.

Since Two weeks now when search something in the address bar it is redirected in "Yahoo search engine"

How having checked the pattern "Safari>Preferences>Search> Search Engine"

I can see that my default engine is still Google(Google is the default engine I like )

But still if I search something in address bar "it is redirected on Yahoo" not on Google and results of the search are not optimal as usually with Google.

Please Can anyone help to delete or remove Yahoo as my default engine search?

It is behaving like a virus.

Any help or comment is welcome

Comment: As this is about changing the functionality of a browser, it belongs on [su], not [webapps.se].

Answer (score 1):

When you open Safari, click on the second button from the right (it is the one with the magnifying glass inside of the circle). click on it and uncheck the checkbox that states: "Yahoo Powered Search as default". Once this is deselected, it should do the trick.